# WCF Service is slow after few iterations

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, service

I am new to WCF Services. I have created a wsHTTPBinding WCF service.

While I am using the WCF Service in my Client application(application contains text box and submit button) it is very slow after few iterations (after six or seventh iteration).

I checked the web.config file. I increased the buffersize in server and client. But I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: are you opening each time a new channel ?

Comment: No i am not using the ChannelFactory Method. I used SOAP method in an ASP.NET application..

Comment: it dowsnt matter. are you each time creating a new proxy ?

Comment: No. I Hosted in IIS and so i dont created proxy.

Comment: Does the same happen when you call the service code directly?

Comment: I solved. Just changed the code by using the ChannelFactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend enabling [WCF trace logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx) which you can use to get the timings for each request, and possibly some visibility into what it is doing. If that lends no useful details, it would probably be easiest to just use a profiler to get the performance data for several requests.